# Make file order the same in "git diff" and Azure Devops

Tags: git, azure-repos, alphabetical-sort

When I'm looking at files modified using `git diff`, I see the following (filenames modified, I use more meaningful names in real life!):

```
/DN/B/F/B.F.S.T/FRT.cs
/DN/B/F/B.F/L/OSL.cs
```

However, in Azure Devops, when looking at the files changed in a pull request, I see the following:

```
/DN/B/F/B.F/L/OSL.cs
/DN/B/F/B.F.S.T/FRT.cs
```

How can I make the alphabetical sorting of files consistent between the two?

Comment: Do you mean maybe `git diff --name-only`?  Just `git diff` doesn't output just file paths in my experience.

Comment: @CryptoFool True, but the contents of the files aren't relevant here.

Comment: I get that. But you're talking about behavior to the level of the ordering of file names.  I'd think it important to be clear on just what is emitting those file names.